# PHP : Simple routing doesn't work with home page

Tags: php, routes

I am trying to create simple routing for my website by PHP. I create the index page containing the routes and three other pages (home.php, about.php and notfound.html).

index.php code:

```
<?php
$path =trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$routes = [
    ''=> 'home.php',
    'aboutus'=> 'aboutus.php',
    
];
if (array_key_exists($path, $routes) ) {
    require $routes[$path];
  }else {
    require 'notfound.html';
  }
?>
```

When I type the *aboutus* the page loads correct. But when I want to load the home.php file it will load the notfound.html.
Where is my error?

Note: All four files are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

The **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** will return **/** when you try to access your index site.

So you change your $routes Array to the following:

```
$routes = [
    '/' => 'home.php',
    'aboutus' => 'aboutus.php',
];
```

Comment: no need for '/' because i used trim ,but i tried that also and didn't work

Comment: even when i use trim, to trim the REQUEST_URI, i still get the /.

Comment: as i used your code by printing (($routes[$path])) it gaves me error :  Undefined index:

Comment: PHP version 7.3.12

Comment: `trim()` removes whitespace from the start and end of the value, not slashes. Do a `var_dump($path)` on line 3 to see which array key shall be used.